# How to control the mutiple buttons and just only one button ishighlight by swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to switch my seven buttons in UIScrollView.
When I click a button(tag=1), it'll highlight.
Then I click another button(tag=2), it'll highlight and unhighlight button(tag=1).
How to control them?
Thanks.

```
for i in 1...7 {
        customButton = customButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60))
        customButton?.tag = i
        customButton?.center = CGPoint(x: (-50)+(CGFloat(i)*100), y: 30)

        customButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        scrollView.addSubview(customButton!)
 }

@objc func buttonClick(sender: UIButton) {

    //how to highlight clicked button and unhighlight other buttons

    switch sender.tag {
        case 1:
            break
        case 2:
            break
        case 3:
            break
        case 4:
            break
        case 5:
            break
        case 6:
            break
        case 7:
            break
        default:
            break
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This for loop will iterate through all subviews of the scrollView. And it changes the `isHighlighted` property by comparing the `sender` object.

```
@objc func buttonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    for case let button as UIButton in scrollView.subviews
    {
      button.isHighlighted = sender == button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create outlet collection of all button and give tag
2. set the same action for all button

   ```
    class MyViewController: UIViewController {

       // collection of uibutton
       @IBOutlet var barItems: [UIButton]!

       var selectedItem: Int? { // setting nil will deselect all item
            set {
                  barItems.forEach { (button) in
                     let isSelected = button.tag == newValue
                     button.isSelected = isSelected
                  }
            }
            get {
                  return barItems.first(where: {$0.isSelected})?.tag
            }
       }

       // Same action for all button
       @IBAction func onItemClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
            selectedItem = sender.tag
        }
     }
   ```